# assign empty 'var' global variable in controller codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter, global-variables

in some code i'm trying to use some global variables are assigned with empty values but I'm not sure why this was necessary.

here's the code:

```
<?php

class Bank_model extends MY_Model
{
  var $id = "";
  var $subject = "";
  var $amt_paid = "";

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function getSellableItems($id){
```

Can someone help me understand the purpose of assigning these var $... variables?

thank you,

tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, these are not global variables.  They are object instance variables only accessible through an object.  It's not uncommon to go ahead and assign these sort of variables default values.

Furthermore, the var keyword is no longer used much which sort of implies you may be following a very old tutorial or example.  Look for examples using private/protected/public.

I would suggest that you work you way through the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: thanks Cerad, can you explain a little further about what is purpose "go(ing) ahead and assign these sort of variables default values"?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, predefined class variables and dynamically-defined object variables are sometimes treated differently. It really depends on the code you've written that accesses these variables. Without that bit of code, your question is a bit too ambiguous to answer more clearly, I'm afraid.